# Is it possible to specify a from email address when inviting users to AAD using Application permission User.Invite.All

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an application leveraging the Microsoft Graph SDK for C# and I have registered that application to use the Application Permission User.Invite.All. I would like to specify the email address the invitation should come from.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the address if you use the default invitation email.

If you want a custom sender address, you'll need to send the invite email yourself through some email provider.
You can disable the default email send with:

```
"sendInvitationMessage": false
```

In the response, you will get `inviteRedeemUrl`.
This is the link you need to send to the user so they can accept the invite.